# How to set multiple values in checklist-value in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have below code.

```
<input icheck type="checkbox" checklist-model="WBSDataSelectedPhase[$index]"   checklist-value="x.phase" style="float:right">
```

Right now in checklist-value="x.phase" , but i need to set multiple comma separated values in checklist-value like
        checklist-value="x.phase,x.parent_id"
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Argument type of checklist-value is string. Expressions can't be written there. So, instead of passing the value , object can be passed as argument and then necessary modification can be done in .js file to get the desired output.            checklist-value="x" can be used instead of checklist-value="x.phase"